# SAML metadata provided by third party

Tags: authentication, metadata, saml, saml-2.0

I'm working on implementing an SSO feature as a service provider (SP).
I was looking into what was necessary for exposing the SAML metadata, and found out that there is a great Wikipedia article about SAML metadata: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_metadata.
In the chapter [Metadata-driven interoperability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_metadata#Metadata-driven_interoperability), they compare static metadata configuration vs dynamic, and basically explain why the saml metadata should be given dynamically. However, they also talk about using a trusted third party as the provider for the metadata (as shown in this [figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_metadata#/media/File:SAML_Web_Browser_SSO_With_Automated_Metadata_Exchange.png)). I haven't found much information on this kind of setup, so I was wondering what are the pros and cons when using a third party for SAML metadata vs not using one ?

Answer (score 0):

Many internal sites use SAML and do not expose the Service Provider metadata.  There is no real reason to as most identity providers provide a method to upload the xml or force you to enter the configuration manually.  With the 8 or so IdPs I have used I have not seen any that allow you to pull the data from a URL.

While most things in the metadata are not particularly sensitive it does provide information that only the Identity Provider needs.